# Linear transformation and its eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm struggling with this problem:

**If one have the transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2: T(\vec{x})=k\vec{x}$ where $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the transformation.**

So I know that the definition of eigenvectors and eigenvalue is given by the equation $$A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}$$

So given this, is not the eigenvalue of the tranformation equal to $k$ and the eigenvector equal to $\vec{x}$? Is it so simple?

Comment: all vectors are eigenvectors of this transformation

Comment: All vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue of $k,$ so any basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a basis for the eigenspace.

Comment: @Stephen Donovan. So you say that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue k. By looking at the equations I wrote, I see what you mean. But do not eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue have to be linearly dependent? If I take two vectors from $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example $\vec{a}=(1,0)$ and $\vec{b}=(2,5)$, how can they be two eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue $k$ when they are not linearly independent?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. Did you mean to write two linearly independent vectors in your last comment? I see by the way that I meant to write this in one of my last comments: If I take two vectors from R2, for example a⃗ =(1,0) and b⃗ =(2,5), how can they be two eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue k when they are not linearly DEPENDENT? I wrote the word I changed in bold to make it clear what I changed

Comment: Two linearly independent eigenvectors could correspond to the same eigenvalue; cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016891/can-two-eigenvectors-share-one-eigenvalue)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner.Thank you! The question you gave the link to was very helpful. Appreciate your help!